# Backbone collection triggering unknown error after fetch

Tags: jquery, json, rest, backbone.js, marionette

I have realized some changes in the technologies that i have been using, however, from now, suddenly i am not able to consume a RESTful service provided correctly and with a right json parse. By the simple call of fetch for a backbone collection the error is not clear enough to debug by myself. Due that, i wish someone could tell me what is going on so far.

NOTE: the restful service was working properly before the versions of my new app.

I have a restful service configured by a Spring Application as described below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/shop")
public class EstabelecimentoController {
     @Autowired
     private EstabelecimentoService estabelecimentoService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<EstabelecimentoVo> getAll(@RequestParam( value = "type", required = false ) String type) {   
        List<EstabelecimentoVo> estabelecimentos = estabelecimentoService.findAllVo();          
        return estabelecimentos; 
    }

}
```

my webapp use backbone, marionette, requirejs, jquery. This is my configuration using requirejs:

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'lib',
    //path mappings for module names not found directly under baseUrl
    paths: {

        app:                    '../app/app',
        router:                 '../app/router',

        jquery:                 'jquery/jquery-2.0.2',
        jqueryui:               'jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min',       

        jqmconfig:              'jqm/jqm-config',
        jqm:                    'jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min',
        jqvalidator:            'jquery/jquery.validate.min', 
        jcookie:                'jquery/jquery.cookie',

        underscore:             'underscore/underscore',
        text:                   'require/text-2.0.10',

        backbone:               'backbone/backbone-1.1.2',
        marionette:             'backbone/marionette/backbone.marionette',
        wreqr :                 'backbone/marionette/backbone.wreqr',
        babysitter:             'backbone/marionette/backbone.babysitter',
        json2:                  'outras/json2',

        controllers:            '../app/controllers',
        models:                 '../app/models',
        collections:            '../app/collections',
        views:                  '../app/views',
        templates:              '../app/templates',
        session:                '../app/utils/session'

//          basic:          '../lib/api/default',

    },
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
            //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
            //backbone.js
            deps: ['jquery', 'jqm', 'jqueryui', 'underscore'],
            //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
            //module value.
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        marionette: {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore','backbone','wreqr'],
            exports: 'Backbone.Marionette'
        },
        jqueryui: {
            exports: "$",
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        jqmconfig: ['jquery'],
        jqm: ['jquery','jqmconfig']
    },
    config: {
        text: {
            useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
                // allow cross-domain requests
                // remote server allows CORS
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my collection which i'm trying to fetch

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','models/shop/estabelecimento'],

        function ($, _, Backbone, Estabelecimento){
    'use strict';
    var EstabelecimentoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        // This is the model of the collection
        model: Estabelecimento,

        url : "http://192.168.0.100:8080/marketmobile/shop",
    });

    return EstabelecimentoCollection;
});
```

ItemView with fetch call to the method:

```
define(['marionette',
        'models/shop/estabelecimento',
        'collections/estabelecimentoCollection',
        'text!templates/content/shop/listShop.html'],
        function(Marionette, 
             Shop,
             ShopCollection,
             listShopTemplate
        ){

    var ListShopView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        //initialize template
        template: _.template(listShopTemplate),

        getAll:function(){
            //set callback of the event "fetchCompleted:Books" 
            //this.collection.bind('fetchCompleted:Shops', this.render, this);
            var self = this;
            this.collection.fetch();
        },

        onRender: function(){
            this.trigger("renderCompleted:Shops",this);
        }

    });
    return ListShopView;
});
```

call:
/* 
 * The controller is basically just a collection of methods that correspond
 * to routes and are called by the application router.
 */

```
define([

        // Application.
        'app',
        // Misc.
        'session',

        'views/main',
        'views/estabelecimentos',
        'collections/estabelecimentoCollection'

        ], function(App, session, MainView, ListShopView, EstabelecimentoCollection) {
    'use strict';

    return {

        // The main page.
        index: function() {
            console.log('called index-controller');

        },

        // The list shop page.
        listShop: function() {
            console.log('called listshop-controller');
            var estabelecimentoListView = new ListShopView({collection: new EstabelecimentoCollection() });
            estabelecimentoListView.bind('renderCompleted:Shops', App.regionMain.show(estabelecimentoListView), this);
            estabelecimentoListView.getAll();
        }
    };

});
```

when the request is done, i've got a 200 response from the server but it still doesn't have any data content pointing to jquery-2.0.2.js (line 7858).

Return from browser:

```
GET http://192.168.0.100:8080/marketmobile/shop 200 OK 76ms
```

jquery-2.0.2.js (line 7858):

```
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

Has anybody had this problem before?? Thank you all in advance

Comment: Is there all your code, didn't forget you anything?

Comment: Everything essencial to come up this issue!! I've just changed from Backbone to Marionette